# Where Should Executable Resource Files be Installed Using the CMake install Command?

Tags: c++, cmake, resources

I am starting to get the hang of CMake now, but one question has essentially stumped me. Suppose I had a project structure such as the following:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    └── resources
        └── text_file.txt
```

In this example, `main.cpp` relies on `resources/text_file.txt`, including it using `std::ifstream fileReader{ "text_file.txt" }`. Thus, in my top level `CMakeLists.txt` file, I have the following line:

```
file(COPY src/resources DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src)
```

This command works for the build directory and all my resources (text files, images, and all the like are accessible to my built application). However, this *does not* really work well for installing using the `install` command and `make install`. For example, if I wanted to install the executable, I could use:

```
install(TARGETS test_executable DESTINATION bin)
```

Where `test_executable` is the name of the executable. On the other hand, installing this resources folder seems a little bit more tricky. My initial thought was to "install" this folder into `bin` as well so that my executable could access it, but then I decided this was a bad idea, since:

1. The `bin` folder is meant for executables, not resource files.
2. (I am not entirely sure about this one) `resources` is a fairly common name for a folder containing resources, so putting them in `bin` could be risky. If the best practice *is* to put resources in a `resources` folder in `bin`, then wouldn't this be a problem for other applications that also had a `resources` folder? (I realize this wouldn't be a problem if I just renamed the folder, but that isn't the point)

This leads to my question: *What should the install location of my resource files be when I am using CMake so that my built executable can access them using the file path shown above?* Should it be in `bin`, or is there some other folder dedicated to this role? How do video games, which have a lot of resource files, handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I did a bit more research, and found [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-windows-program-files/27257#27257), which states that the relevant resource files are stored in `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/share`, which is used for storing platform independent files.

In order to get this path, most apps configure a script that stores it in a variable depending on the platform.

Comment: Since this question is 3.5 years old at the time of writing this, I was wondering: is it still the technique you use today to achieve this? I am looking for doing this as well and am kind of unsure.